# Show windows directory structure in html using jquery or jsp or javascript.

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp

I want to show windows directory structure in a web page so that user can select a file and upload to server for backup.Using java am able to get all the directory's and files but I don't how to  proceed further to show them in web page as in windows directory structure.I already saw many jquery plugins for that.All they are just static.I need a dynamic Tree structure .It must show all user drives,directory's and files. Please help me to find a solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *"..so that user can select a file and upload to server for backup."*  Offer them a [file input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4).  Once the user chooses to select a file, the web browser will typically open the OS' own file chooser.

Answer (score 4):

Try jQuery File Tree [plugin](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/).

[Demo](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/demo/)

Comment: Uh, upvoting requires a minimum of 15 reputation.